# Hadamard’s Theorem from Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's handbook

Tags: matrices, summation, inequality

In the book [http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/~svincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/%7Esvincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf) on page 1077 I found one interesting theorem:

[image]

I took an arbitrary matrix and tested this theorem. The result is the following:

```
m = {{1, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 1}};
m // MatrixForm;
Det[m];
Table[Abs[m[[i, i]]] > 
  Sum[Abs[m[[i, j]]] Boole[i != j], {j, 1, 3}], {i, 1, 3}]
```

Although the determinant of the matrix is non-zero, 2 of the 3 inequalities do not hold. It is possible to choose such a matrix that all conditions will not be met, but the matrix will have a non-zero determinant. For example:

```
m = {{1, 0, 5}, {5, 1, 0}, {10, 0, 1}};
```

Is this a counterexample to the theorem, is the theorem applicable only to matrices of a certain class, or am I just wrong in my calculations?

Comment: Theorem says that if inequalities hold, the determinant is not zero. If inequalities do not hold, there is not statement about the determinant being  zero or not zero. No contradiction of your example and the theorem.

Comment: @RomaLee Now it is clear! Indeed, the converse assertion does not guarantee the fulfillment of the given condition. But are there theorems for the lower bound of the determinant that would be free from this shortcoming?

Comment: There is no [if and only if] just like in the nessesary condition of series convergence, aka https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth-term_test

Comment: This result appears as the [Levy-Desplanques theorem](https://planetmath.org/levydesplanquestheorem) on PlanetMath. The Wikipedia page for [diagonally dominant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) doesn't give it a name and instead takes it as a consequence of the Greshgorin circle theorem.

Comment: @Semiclassical A related [Hadamard Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality) states that the modulus of the determinant of a matrix is always less than or equal to the product of the Euclidean norms of the columns of this matrix. It seems to me that this can be used as a necessary condition for the non-negativity of the determinant. This inequality is also related to the [Scalar Triple Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product). It seems to be a good and at the moment the simplest criterion known to me.